vsslproxy: Client {IP} failed SSL negotiation (ssl/record/ssl3_record.c/350): error:1408F1BB:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:bad record type)
During the last few weeks, some client complained that they are "kicked" from our website and after some digging around, we found that the load balancer return this error for those client (same IP, same time, so we are pretty sure that what "kick" them)
Here what I know

Client browse in our website correctly (asp classic page if that matter?)
Client get to an ajax call and receive this error: vsslproxy: Client {IP} failed SSL negotiation (ssl/record/ssl3_record.c/350): error:1408F1BB:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:bad record type)
Since the ajax call failed and that ajax call is required, we redirect the user to an error page.

I used https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html and that website tell me that my ciphers / certificate are good. The score of our website is A+. In the "handshake simulation section", for the same browser, everything is fine, is green. (but I guess this website doesn't test ajax call)
We use KEMP as load balancer technologie and the support has been non helpful at all.
The browser of  the client which produce those error are up to date (some are chrome last version, some edge, some firefox, some on mac).
The client can navigate through our website just fine and only the ajax (javascript call with jquery) produce this error for some client.
What worse, is that the same client can sometimes complete his transaciton if he retry, if he's lucky.
We tried adding more log to no avail. Googling this specific error (bad record type) doesn't help at all and KEMP support only tell us "its a client problem" but, if its was, why does it sometimes work the second or third time?
Any thought, help or anything would greatly help me as I've been bashing my head on the desk with this problem.
Thank you

Does the AJAX call go to the same domain as the original page load? Is this a specific client, or many clients? If many, are there any correlations between clients (same ISP, same geographical area, etc.)?

My usual go-to solution here would be to capture packets on the machine (probably the load balancer) with a filter  for the specific client that’s having the problem. The packet capture won’t be able to see inside the SSL transaction, but it should be able to see if the handshakes are being completed correctly. Here it sounds very much like the handshake is failing with some random (non-SSL) traffic being inserted.

Yes, the ajax call go to the same domain as the original call (same protocol too, always HTTPS). This is many different client, with different browser. We mostly sell in the same place (province of quebec) so all client are from there.
I cant reproduce the problem myself so Id have to "capture packets" from all until the problem occur again and then analyze it?
